# How to stop AVPlayer at specific time?

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

## My code :

```
    playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[playerController.player currentItem]];

    playerController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    [playerController.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

    playerController.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;

    [playerController.player play];

    [self presentViewController:playerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here I stop the video in specific time.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Stopping video at 3min34sec for example ?

Comment: Will this specific time always be the same ?

Comment: no some condition 3sec or 4sec

Comment: I'm writing some code for you, will post in a few minutes !

Answer (score 4):

What you have to do is :

Create the following property in .h file :

```
@property (strong) id playerObserver;
```

Add this code in .m file :

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];

[player play];

self.playerObserver = [player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:@[[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMake(1, 1000)]] queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Video started playing");

    [player performSelector:@selector(pause) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0]; //will pause player after 3.0 seconds
    [player removeTimeObserver:self.playerObserver];
}];
```

This code will track when the video starts playing. Then, after whatever-time you want (here 3 seconds), it will pause the player. At least, we remove the observer on the player.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I tried the code before posting, **it works**. Maybe your implementation is quite different. For your second issue, I think that your first fix is responsible of that, because `pause` couldn't make a playing loop.

Comment: You said that you add `playerController.player.currentItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(timeDuration, 1);` and I think it's this line that cause the bug.

Comment: please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803475/play-a-video-in-avplayer-for-a-specific-duration-in-swift3-ios

Answer (score 2):

**SWFIT 3 Version** come from @Anthonin C 's answer.

```
player = AVPlayer(url: tmpURL)
player?.perform(#selector(player?.pause), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
```